# How to solve gridview headers disappears bug on clicking next page of jquery datatable?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have added a jquery datatable on a gridview.When i click on 2nd page the gridview headers disappears and clicking back on first page they are shown again.

My code is

```
    <head runat="server">
    <link href="Stylesheets/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`enter code here`
    <link href="Stylesheets/demo_table.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.display').dataTable({
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "iDisplayLength": 10,
                "aaSorting": [],
                "bDestroy": true,
                "bRetrieve": true,
                'bProcessing': true,
                'bServerSide': false
            })

            ApplyDataTable('.display');
        });
    </script>
     </head>



 <asp:GridView ID="gvReport" TabIndex="11" class="display" runat="server" Height="176px" Width="100%"
                            BackColor="#EEEEEE" Font-Size="10pt" Font-Names="Verdana" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                            DataKeyField="TaskId" HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Name="Verdana" ShowFooter="True"
                            OnRowDataBound="gvReport_RowDataBound">
                            <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" ForeColor="White" BackColor="Black">
                            </HeaderStyle>
                            <FooterStyle BorderColor="Black" BackColor="Black"></FooterStyle>
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="FullName" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ReadOnly="True"
                                    HeaderText="Resource" HeaderStyle-Width="250px" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ReadOnly="True"
                                    HeaderText="Date" HeaderStyle-Width="200px" />
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Score" HeaderStyle-Width="100px">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblScore" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
```

Also search textbox on the right corner is not searching any record in the grid.
How to solve header disappear problem and searching in jquery datatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you realize that this plugin requires that the table element has its headers to be defined in the thead section. This is how a standard html table should look like:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Data1</td>
            <td>Data2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In fact this is the standard: headers in the `thead` and data/content in the `tbody`. But the tbody part turns out isn't a problem. This plugin works even without it!

Now, the easiest way to do so at the moment is to manipulate that via js in order to get the first row into a thead. After which the code you've written might work.

Here is a sample.

```
    $(function () {
        var gv = $('#GridView1');
        var thead =$('<thead/>');
        thead.append(gv.find('tr:eq(0)'));
        gv.append(thead);
        gv.dataTable({            
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "iDisplayLength": 10,
            "aaSorting": [],
            "bDestroy": true,
            "bRetrieve": true,
            'bProcessing': true,
            'bServerSide': false                
        });            
    });
```

You'd need to modify it to make it work in your case.

A more complicated way to do so is to extend the GridView and override its markup generation such that it generate the required sections.